# How to find nested attribute ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, nested-attributes

How can I show the `:user_id` of dueler in the edit page?

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= @dueler.user_id %>
<% end %>
```

**rails c**

```
Duel.last
 id: 11,
 consequence: "bad",
 reward: "good",

Dueler.find(15)
 id: 15,
 user_id: 78, # I want to get this ID
 challenge_id: 179,
 duel_id: 11,

Dueler.last
 id: 16,
 user_id: 15,
 challenge_id: 190,
 duel_id: 11,
```

**duels_controller**

```
@dueler = Dueler.find(params[:user_id]) # THIS GIVES ERROR: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DuelsController#edit Couldn't find Dueler with 'id'=
```

### BY REQUEST

**FULL duels_controller**

```
class DuelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_duel, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @duels = Duel.joins(:duelers).all
    respond_with(@duels)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def new
    @duel = Duel.new
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def edit
    @dueler = Dueler.find_by(user_id: params[:dueler][:user_id]) # Sri Vishnu Totakura's Suggested Change
  end

  def create
    @duel = Duel.new(duel_params)
    @duel.save
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def update
    @duel.update(duel_params)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def destroy
    @duel.destroy
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  private
    def set_duel
      @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
    end

    def duel_params
      params.require(:duel).permit(:consequence, :reward, duelers_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :challenge_id, :accept])
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to pass the `id` of `Dueler` through url, and then `Dueler.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @ArupRakshit If I switch it to `:id` the error goes away, but then the id says `15` instead of `78` for both duelers

Comment: are `Duel` and `Dueler` related somehow? Associations?

Answer (score 1):

---

> Since you updated your question, my answer is invalid! You should have added the controller actions initially! My suggestion would not work for your problem.
>
> I'm not deleting the answer because there is some discussion in the
>   comments.

---

You need to use `find_by` instead of `find`.

`find` always queries on `id`. If you need to find based on other columns, you use `find_by`

Your code should be:

```
@dueler = Dueler.find_by(user_id: params[:dueler][:user_id])
```

Documentation:

- [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)
- [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

Comment: Thanks Sri! I put your code in. I get this error: `undefined method 'user_id' for nil:NilClass` for `<%= @dueler.user_id %>`.

Comment: the means, there is no `Dueler` object that has the `user_id` that was passed in `params` in the database. Are you sure there is a `Dueler` record in the database with the `user_id` you are passing?

Comment: Yes sir. I showed it in the rails c. I actually have two `duelers` for the one `duel` . I'll update question to show both.

Comment: What is the value of  `params[:user_id]` in the controller action? Do a `puts params[:user_id]` and see.

Comment: Or try `Dueler.find_by(user_id: params[:dueler][:user_id])`

Comment: Yea that gives `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: `[5] pry(main)> puts params[:user_id]
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'params' for main:Object
from (pry):5:in __pry__`

Comment: Try `Dueler.find_by(user_id: 78)` in your `rails console`

Comment: That worked: `Dueler.find_by(user_id: 78)
  Dueler Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "duelers".* FROM "duelers" WHERE "duelers"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 78]]
=> #<Dueler:0x007fb6a9e235f8
 id: 10,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 179,
 created_at: Sun, 24 Jul 2016 20:30:44 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 24 Jul 2016 20:30:44 EDT -04:00,
 duel_id: 8,`

Comment: That means you are not receiving the params correctly on to your controller. Why don't you add your whole controller code into the question

Comment: In the duels/edit.html.erb I have `<%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %><%= render 'edit_dueler_fields', :f => dueler %><% end %>` and then in duels/_edit_dueler_fields.html.erb the `number_field` is correctly filled with the dueler's respective user id: `<%= f.number_field :user_id %>`

Comment: Looking at your updated question. My answer is invalid! I'm not deleting it because the comments have some discussion